# How to have multiple `let Some()` in a single line where the second `let` is dependent on the first?

Tags: rust

Is something like this possible where both `let Some(...)` are in the same line and the second `let` is dependent on the first `let`?

```
let Some(h) = socket.req_parts().headers.get("room"), let Some(room) = h.to_str() else {
    return;
};
```

This solution:

[How to write multiple condition in if let statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293804/how-to-write-multiple-condition-in-if-let-statement)

proposes using tuples but I am not sure how to do that when second `let` is dependant on first.

Comment: You may want to ask yourself why you want to do this.

Comment: @Chris I come from `Swift` background which allows this. It can be useful when one needs access to an optional as well as another optional derived from first optional. Example in this Rust code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925633/1634905

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, you can't do two separate dependent `let Some()`s at the same time, when the dependency is through a function call. In your link comments show examples of "dependent" matches with `@` identifiers:

```rust
if let Some(c @ Some(7)) = a
```

This works because it's in a sense equivalent to

```rust
if let Some(Some(7)) = a
```

with the addition of binding the `Some(7)` to `c`. The dependency is expressed on the left-hand-side, in the pattern. You can't put your function call there.

Since you want to go into the `else` clause if either `h` or `room` would be `None`, you can instead use `Option.and_then`, which takes a function returning an `Option` as its argument, and only applies it to `Some`. This is cleanest if you just need `room`:

```rust
let Some((h, room)) = socket
    .req_parts()
    .headers
    .get("room")
    .and_then(|h| h.to_str())
```

But you could also use tuples to get both `room` and `h`:

```rust
let Some((h, room)) = socket
    .req_parts()
    .headers
    .get("room")
    .and_then(|h| h.to_str().map(|room| (h, room)))
```

Comment: This does seem to work but seems a bit "complex"? In the solution I linked in my post, one of the comment talks about using `@`. Do you know how to use it for this? I can't understand the syntax for it.

Comment: @sudoExclamationExclamation thanks for pointing that out. I think the answer is that you can't, let me edit to explain.

Comment: `h.to_str()` returns another `Option` in the OP's example, so you'd need to use `and_then` instead of `map`. Or match `Some(Some(room))`.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for catching that. I'll edit.