# Rust "borrowed value does not live long enough" disappears when I remove a piece of code

Tags: rust

I am using the solution in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925633/1634905

My code looks like:

```
fn get_room_header<'a>(socket: &'a SocketRef) -> Option<&'a str> {
    socket.req_parts().headers.get("room")?.to_str().ok()
}

async fn on_connect(socket: SocketRef) {

    println!("on_connect");

    let Some(room) = get_room_header(&socket) else {
        println!("No room sent: {:?}",socket.req_parts());
        _ = socket.disconnect();
        return;
    };

    // println!("Room: {:?}",room);

    let _ = socket.leave_all();
    let _ = socket.join(room);//if I comment out this line, it no longer throws error

}
```

This doesn't compile and gives an error:

```
`socket` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enough
main.rs(61, 1): `socket` dropped here while still borrowed
main.rs(46, 21): binding `socket` declared here
main.rs(50, 22): argument requires that `socket` is borrowed for `'static`
```

Screenshot of error:

[image]

If I comment out the line `let _ = socket.join(room);`, then it no longer throws the error. Why's this?

The `join()` function is from `rust_socketio` crate:

https://github.com/1c3t3a/rust-socketio/tree/main

It looks like this:

```
pub fn join(&self, rooms: impl RoomParam) -> Result<(), A::Error> {
    self.ns.adapter.add_all(self.id, rooms)
}

pub trait RoomParam: 'static {
    /// The type of the iterator returned by `into_room_iter`.
    type IntoIter: Iterator<Item = Room>;

    /// Convert `self` into an iterator of rooms.
    fn into_room_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
}
```

Comment: There isn't quite enough information to answer the question; _at a minimum_ we need to see the signature of the `join()` function and of its containing `impl` block, but Stack Overflow strongly prefers _reproducible_ code. Please try to condense your situation into code we could actually try compiling to reproduce the error.

Comment: @KevinReid I have added the `join()` function to my post. It's from `socketioxide` crate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rust
pub fn join(&self, rooms: impl RoomParam) -> Result<(), A::Error> {
```

This says that whatever you pass to `join()` must be of a type that implements `RoomParam`.

```rust
pub trait RoomParam: 'static {
```

This says that one of the requirements of implementing `RoomParam` is that it is `'static`. Since you passed a `&'a str`, the compiler concludes that `'a = 'static`. This then requires, through the signature of `get_room_header()`,

```rust
fn get_room_header<'a>(socket: &'a SocketRef) -> Option<&'a str> {
```

that `socket` also be borrowed for `'static`. But it is not, and in fact you drop it at the end of the function, so you get a “borrowed value does not live long enough” error.

---

Now as to solving the problem, the general thing to keep in mind is: if you get an error that something must be borrowed for `'static`, that most often means that *it shouldn't be borrowed at all*. Don't try to use a `&str` as the `RoomParam` — use an owned value.

If we go to [the documentation for `RoomParam`](https://docs.rs/socketioxide/0.10.2/socketioxide/operators/trait.RoomParam.html), we can see it is implemented for several types and you should probably use `String` — that is, convert your `&str` to `String`:

```rust
let _ = socket.join(room.to_owned());
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Your answer helped me change my function to return `Option<String>` instead of the original `Option<&'a str>`. So now, my function is: `fn get_room_header(socket: &SocketRef) -> Option<String> {
    socket.req_parts().headers.get("room")?.to_str().ok().map(|s| s.to_string())
}`